# ReactNavigation headerRight doesn't show

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a nested navigation setup with `App.js` calling a component `NavigationMain` as per the below.

**App.js**

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="NavigationMain"
              component={NavigationMain}
              options={({ route }) => ({
                headerShown: true,
                title: getHeaderTitle(route),
              })}
            />
          ...
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Note in the above I also use a helper function `getHeaderTitle` so that each individual screen has a unique title.

**NavigationMain.js**

```
function NavigationMain() {
    return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      ...
    >
      ...
      <Tab.Screen
          name='Plans'
          component={PlansView}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Plans',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="certificate" color={color} size={26} />
                ),
            }}
      />    
    </Tab.Navigator>
    );}
```

`NavigationMain` in turn calls the `PlansView` component for when the user attempts to view this particular screen.

**PlansView.js**

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, {
    useLayoutEffect,
  } from "react";
import { navigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const PlansView = ({ navigation }) => {
    
  // Set header to contain add new plan button
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Add Plan")}
        >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="plus-thick" color="black" size={26} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Plans</Text>
        </View>
    )};

    export default PlansView;
```

I try to use `useLayoutEffect` to set `headerRight`. This however does not work, and while the Plans header shows as expected, the headerRight is blank (nothing shows up).

I suspect this is because the headerSettings for certain items (ie. the title are being set at the parent navigator level.) But I have no idea how to change this so I can I set the headerRight with `useEffect`.

[image: screenshot of the plans view]

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

```
 <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerBackVisible: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Header"
        component={Header}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1C3879',
          },
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                Alert.alert('Confirm', 'Hello', [
                  {text: 'CANCEL', onPress: () => console.log('')},
                  {
                    text: 'PRESS',
                    onPress: () => {
                      alert("hiii");
                    },
                  },
                ])
              }>
              <View
                style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 5, borderRadius: 5}}>
                <Text style={{color: '#1C3879'}}>TEST</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
    
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 22,
          },
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: That doesn't take into account the nested navigation and doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately.